# Firefox 4 and 5: invalid 'in' operand this._sandBox - resource://gre/components/nsProxyAutoConfig.js

Tags: firefox, javascript, sandbox

This error drives me insane:
invalid 'in' operand this._sandBox - resource://gre/components/nsProxyAutoConfig.js line:91

in firefox 4 and 5. It started to malfunction when i did the upgrade from 3.6 to 4.

I have search the internet about the error but seems to be an old one, it first occur in Firefox 2.8 and fixed in 3.x and above.

What i have done to try to fix this:
- Upgrade from 4 to 5 - no effect
- Uninstall Firefox and reinstall it - no effect
- Removing caches - no effect
- Modified the resource://gre/components/nsProxyAutoConfig.js, by unpacking it's archive omni.jar (which is actually a zip file), fix the error with a try{} catch(e){} statement - clear cache again - NO EFFECT

It seems to be there is a compiled or cached version of nsProxyAutoConfig.js because the error is refering to the same line, and there is a comment of my fix!

```
    // Fix by EH, returning error in FF    <- This is now line 91
   try {
   if (!("FindProxyForURL" in this._sandBox))
      return null;
   } catch (e) { return null; }
```

I need to get rid of this error because there is no fix for it and it stops debugging the scripts of any website so i cannot see the error when there is a error in the javascript. That is very anoying.

Please, does somebody have a solution to this?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure from your description that you're clearing the right caches -- the XUL/XPC fastload caches (-purgecaches command line argument is the easiest way to kill them). The problem itself seems likely to be caused by your proxy configuration -- did you try starting with a new Firefox profile and attempting to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, tried a new upgrade again from 3.6 to Firefox 6, same error. @Nickolay was right, it has something to do with the proxy configuration, but, i didn't touch it!

To get rid from this message go to menu:
Extra|Options|Advanced|Network Tab and open connection settings.
Set Proxy to "No Proxy"

Error is gone.